# Modelling number types and arithmetic operations between them in Java

Tags: java, interface, numbers

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm creating a class hierarchy that represents and has utilities for a lot of linear algebra concepts (both to practice linear algebra and to practice Java, which I'm learning right now).
All went pretty well until I decided to add the different types of numbers, that is, integers, rationals, reals and complex (for now).

What I want is to be able to operate with them (for example, inside a Matrix class) without having to care about which number type I'm operating with, and implement all the operations inside different classes representing each number type.

**What I thought/tried:**

I thought it was a good idea to make an interface called "AnyNumber" (since Number is already taken by the Java API) on which I'd define all the necessary abstract methods, and then implement that interface on each number type class.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to handle class types.

Here is what the interface declaration would look like:

```
public interface AnyNumber {

    public AnyNumber add(AnyNumber other);
    public AnyNumber subtract(AnyNumber other);
    public AnyNumber multiply(AnyNumber other);
    public AnyNumber divide(AnyNumber other);

}
```

This way, I'd be able to operate with any objects that implement the interface by simple calling methods like:

```
number1 = number1.add(number2)
```

**The problems I had**

The problem comes when trying to implement the interface methods on a particular class.
I thought Java understood that the type "AnyNumber" could be any type that implements the interface, so I tried declaring the methods like this:

```
public IntegerNumber add(IntegerNumber other) {
    return new IntegerNumber(this.value + other.value);
}
```

But Eclipse complained that I did not not implement the following method:

```
AnyNumber add(AnyNumber other)
```

Then I though that I could just change the return and argument types to "AnyNumber", but soon realized I couldn't access the variable "value" inside "other" because the interface doesn't define it.

So I thought maybe what I needed was an abstract class that defined all the necessary fields and abstract methods for all the different types of number, but I'm not sure if that's a good approach, since integer numbers just need one field, while rationals need two, and complex need also two but I'd like to name them different. Also, something keeps telling me that an interface makes a lot of sense in this situation..

..So I though maybe what I needed were generics. But I don't yet fully understand them and all my attempts to use them to solve this problem have miserably failed.

**Please help**

I realized I'll not be able to solve this alone... I really want to continue working on this project and learn how to deal with this kind of situations in Java.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement an interface method, the parameter types need to be exactly the same as they are in the interface.  The *return* type doesn't have to be the same--it can be a subclass (this is called *covariance*).  But the parameter types can't be subclasses (this is called *contravariance* and Java doesn't allow it).

The reason is that there's nothing preventing the types of the two `AnyNumber` objects to be different.

```
AnyNumber n1 = new IntegerNumber(123);
AnyNumber n2 = new RealNumber(23.4);
```

Then later, you could say:

```
IntegerNumber n3 = n1.add(n2);
```

Or you can pass `n1` and `n2` as parameters to some other method that tries to do the above.  The point here is that since `n1` and `n2` are declared as `AnyNumber`, the compiler cannot tell, at that point, whether the two objects have the same class.

This means that if you require that the two objects have the same class, you'll have to enforce it yourself, at runtime.

Your implementing class needs to look like

```
public class IntegerNumber implements AnyNumber {

    public IntegerNumber add(AnyNumber other) {  // NOTE: Must be AnyNumber!!
        IntegerNumber otherInteger = (IntegerNumber)other;
            // will throw a ClassCastException at runtime if "other" is, say, RealNumber
        ...
    }
}
```

The rest of the method can use `otherInteger`, which the compiler knows will be an `IntegerNumber` at that point, since you've checked.  There are other things you can do; you can use `instanceof` to check, and control what exception you throw (or what else you do) instead of letting the cast throw the exception.  You could also add mechanisms to handle adding of different `AnyNumber` types, if you choose.

Comment: I see. So I could handle operations between different types of numbers using "instanceof" to check what type the other number is, and then typecasting it, right?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AdriàRicoBlanes Not quite.  If it's a `RealNumber` (i.e. if the object was created with `new RealNumber`), you cannot cast it to an `IntegerNumber`.  You can't cast an `IntegerNumber` to a `RealNumber` either.  To handle an `add` of an `IntegerNumber` and a `RealNumber`, you will have to figure out what to do (probably cast the integer's `value` to a float); to add an `IntegerNumber` and a `RationalNumber`, you'll have to do a little math.

Comment: I know I know, I meant to say "and then typecasting it to the correct type (and dealing with each case in the proper way)", sorry!